# loop in a workbook on worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop on all the worksheets of a workbook and copy-paste in values. Here is my code:

```
Sub paste_hard()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C500")
        rng.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

    Next ws

    Range("A1:C500") = rng

End Sub
```

Problem comes from `rng.Select` and I get the following error:

> Method 'Select' of object 'Range' failed

I am a beginner in vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can only select a range on an active worksheet.  Your error is happening because you're trying to `Select` the range on sheet(s) that are not Active at runtime.

One (ugly) solution would be to put `ws.Activate` inside your loop (before `Set rng = ...`

But [instead of gunking up your code with a bunch of unnecessary `Select` and `Activate` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), do this instead -- if you're simply concerned with the *values*, then you don't need to do anything with `Copy`, `Paste` or `PasteSpecial`:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C500")
    rng.Value = rng.Value

Next ws
```

And voila, 5 lines of code becomes 2 lines of code :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I changed as you suggested, but 2 problems:

Comment: You don't need the object variable and so becomes one line:  `ws.Range("A1:C500") = ws.Range("A1:C500").Value`

Comment: 1 - the active sheet becomes blank (no values on it) and 2- the others worksheets stay as it is

Comment: Sub paste_hard()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C500")
        rng.Value = rng.Value

    Next ws

    Range("A1:C500") = rng

End Sub

Comment: @ExcelHero arguably my method is easier to maintain, because if you ever need to redefine the range, you only need to "fix" the code in one place, instead of two, and this also makes the method easily adaptable to take the range as an argument instead of a procedure-level variable :)

Comment: @phacoo your problem may be he extra `Range("A1:C500") = rng ` before your `End Sub`. Get rid of it :)  -- also, it's really really difficult to read code in the comments, so for future clarifications, it's best to revise the content of your original question, where you can format the code appropriately.  Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yep, I would not do it either, but since you mentioned the two lines of code, I jumped in. But unless I really needed the object variable I would not create it. I would use a With block and only reference the range once.

Comment: @ExcelHero the `With` block would be even better :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah, but then we are at three lines... though could cheat and put it on one.

Comment: Three lines, but only one object reference instead of two @ExcelHero